# Errors when splitting time series data into two in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I have streaming time-series data (BTCUSDT prices) from Binance in form of a `DataFrame` as below.

INITIAL CODE AFTER IMPORTING MODULES

```py
def btc_pairs_trade(msg):
            
    
        if msg['e'] != 'error':
          price['BTCUSDT'].loc[len(price['BTCUSDT'])] = [pd.Timestamp.now(), 
           float(msg['c'])]
          bn=price['BTCUSDT']
          return bn
        else:
          price['error'] = True
```

AND

```py
bsm = ThreadedWebsocketManager()
bsm.start()
bsm.start_symbol_ticker_socket(symbol='BTCUSDT', callback=btc_pairs_trade)
```

AND

```py
## main
while len(price['BTCUSDT']) == 0:
    # wait for WebSocket to start streaming data
    sleep(0.1)
    
sleep(10)
```

```
    date                        price   change
0   2021-10-14 07:41:55.963626  57531.56    -100.18
1   2021-10-14 07:41:56.965003  57531.56    -100.18
2   2021-10-14 07:41:56.971939  57531.56    -100.18
3   2021-10-14 07:41:57.964664  57531.57    -100.18
4   2021-10-14 07:41:57.968422  57531.57    -100.18
```

The idea is to go back to the 'start_time' determined by `now` minus say 5 minutes, using `pd.timedelta`. Then create a new `DataFrame` that will hold the data between `start_time` and now i.e `df2`. From there I proceed with my `if` conditions to run tasks using the prices within the newly created `DataFrame`. The code snippet is as below.

```py
        df = price['BTCUSDT']
        start_time = df.date.iloc[-1] - pd.Timedelta(minutes=5)
        df2 = df.loc[df.date >= start_time]
        if df2.price.iloc[0]-df2.price.iloc[-1]>100:
          try:
        elif df2.price.iloc[0]-df2.price.iloc[-1]<-100:
          try:
```

The problem is when I run the code I get the error below.

```
---> 11     df2 = df.loc[df.date >= start_time]`
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

I thought the error was because of naming the second DataFrame as the first so I changed the second to df2.(I had used df1), but I still get the same problem.
Sometimes the code runs successfully but with the below warning.

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

How do I sort the problem?

Comment: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` doesn't relate to nama of `DataFrame`. please put initial codes for getting data from Binance so i can work with that specific `DataFrame` around your problem.

Comment: @Shayan. Thanks, I have added the initial codes